# What are the benefits of left outer join vs nested aggregate selects to find the newest rows in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing:

```
select * from mytable y
where y.year = (select max(yi.year) 
                from mytable yi
                where yi.person = y.person)
```

Is that better or worse from a performance aspect than:

```
select y.* from mytable y
left outer join mytable y2
  on y.year < y2.year
  and y.person = y2.person
where y2.year is null
```

The explain plan/anecdotal evidence is inconclusive so I am wondering if in general one is better than the other.

Comment: Are you sure those two queries give the same result? It doesn't look like they should.

Comment: I don't know, but the first expresses the intention a lot more clearly than the second to me.

Comment: haven't you forgot to add `y.person = y2.person` into the `ON` condition in the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Maybe you can post the query plan pictures?

Comment: My mistake -- yes, i forgot a join... edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"In general", both queries can produce different execution plans depending on data distribution.

However, assuming that your second query is in fact this:

```
SELECT  y.*
FROM    mytable y
LEFT JOIN
        mytable y2
ON      y2.person = y.person
        AND y2.year > y.year
WHERE   y2.year IS NULL
```

, the `LEFT JOIN` version will most probably be faster, since it will be optimized either to a `HASH ANTI JOIN` or a `HASH JOIN` with filter, depending on whether you have an index on `mytable (person, year)` or not and some other conditions. The subquery version is not optimizeable to an anti join.

You may most probably find these queries more efficient:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable y
WHERE   (y.person , y.year) IN
        (
        SELECT  person, MAX(year)
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                person
        )
```

or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  y.*,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY year DESC) dr
        FROM    mytable y
        )
WHERE   dr = 1
```

, with the first one being more efficient in case of many persons and few years per person, and the second one being the more efficient in the opposite case.

You can replace `DENSE_RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER` which will allow you to get rid of duplicates on `person, MAX(year)` should you ever want to.

Comment: In my test (if person is the PK) the his first query will be optimized into a single inner merge join

Comment: @Magnus: if `person` is a PK, you can replace the whole thing with `SELECT * FROM mytable`.

Comment: What happens if this query is saved as a view?  If I do select from theview where person = :X will it do subquery refactoring or will it only apply the person condition after the entire set of data is generated?  I've had mixed luck when I do nested queries in my views when it comes to this.

Comment: @RenderLn: `Oracle` expands both inline and declared views when optimizing. If you don't specifically instruct the optimizer with `PUSH_PRED`, `MATERIALIZE` and similar hints, the plans will be identical.

Answer (score 1):

They don't look relationally equivalent - the first is doing a correlated subquery on person that's absent in the second.

```
select * from mytable y
 where y.year = (select max(yi.year) 
                   from mytable yi
                  where yi.person = y.person)
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
select [list of columns] 
  from (select [list of columns including year], 
               max(year) over (partition by person) as max_year
          from mytable)
 where year = max_year
```

To avoid the self-join.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Adam's...  From what I read, way faster than any version that uses joins.

```
select *
from (select person, year, ...
      Rank() over (partition by person order by year desc) as Rank
      from mytable)
where Rank = 1
```